# Remove non-breaking space in Yahoo! Pipes

Tags: html, unicode, character, space, yahoo-pipes

I used the XPath Fetch Page module to fetch a page and convert it to a bunch of nodes. One of the nodes has "`2012-07-28&nbsp;00:00`", but the `&nbsp;` appears as a space ("") in Yahoo! Pipes. I also entered the string [here](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?characters=2012-07-28+00%3A00) and it considers it a regular space, though.

How can I convert this non-breaking space to a regular space? I tried using the Regex module, but everything that I try putting in the "find" field does not match the non-breaking space.

I tried using "", "`&nbsp;`", "`&#x0020;`", but none of these work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regexp module {replace: "`\xA0`", with: " "} to convert a non-breaking space to a regular space.

Note: This behavior is undocumented, so may be changed without notice.